# Python ioerror errno 2 no such file or directory pilutil

Tags: python, ioerror

I'm having trouble running a python script using python 2.7.3 on lubuntu 12.10 run through virtual box on an older mac book (summer 2009, model 5,2 perhaps) with an intel processor.

The script seems to detect the video file I specify through the command line and I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong. Here is the trace back and the code and the code which causes the error.

1

```
src_dir = sys.argv[1]
out_dir = sys.argv[2]
bb_dir = sys.argv[3]
vid_name = sys.argv[4]

vid_src_name = src_dir + vid_name
vid_dest_name = out_dir + vid_name
vid_bb_name = bb_dir + vid_name

vid=video.asvideo(vid_src_name,down_factor)
```

2

```
if hasattr(video_source, 'shape') and hasattr(video_source, 'dtype'):
    if len(video_source.shape) == 3:
        video_source.shape = video_source.shape + (1,)

    vshape = video_source.shape
    vdtype = video_source.dtype
    vid = Video(frames=vshape[0], rows=vshape[1], columns=vshape[2], bands=vshape[3], dtype=vdtype, initialise=False)
    vid.V = video_source
    return vid

if not os.path.exists(video_source):
    raise IOError(video_source + ' not found')

    (unusedfh,sample_filename) = tempfile.mkstemp()
 cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "' + video_source + '" -vframes 1 ' + sample_filename+'    %d' + image_ext + ' 2> /dev/null > /dev/null'
 sample_filename = sample_filename + '1' + image_ext
 subp.call(cmd, shell = True)
 sample_img = sp.misc.imread(sample_filename)
```

3.

```
 im = Image.open(name)
```

4.

```
 if mode != "r":
     raise ValueError("bad mode")

 if isStringType(fp):
     import __builtin__
     filename = fp
     fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
```

Output:

```
cody@cody-VirtualBox:~/Dropbox/annotation/Template_Extractor$ python        template_extract_new.py "/home/cody/Work/annotate/UCF50/video/PushUps"     "/home/cody/Dropbox/annotation/template/Pushups" "/home/cody/Dropbox/annotation/bb/PushUps" "/v_PushUps_g01_c01.avi"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "template_extract_new.py", line 192, in <module>
    vid=video.asvideo(vid_src_name,down_factor)
  File "/home/cody/Dropbox/annotation/Template_Extractor/istare/video.py", line 135, in   asvideo
    sample_img = sp.misc.imread(sample_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 102, in imread
    im = Image.open(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1952, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpklcTe61.bmp'
```

The file indicated in the error changes every time and is not there before running but is there after running the command.

I've tried running from uterm, uxterm, and lxterminal (knowing it wouldn't do anything but trying anyways, plus no copy and paste in uterm).

Comment: fix indentation in the `tempfile.mkstemp()` line

Comment: It's hard to understand the code in the way it's formatted but is it not the case that ``ffmpeg`` has failed and not created the tmpfile(sample_filename) - I suggest you print the ``cmd`` and then run that on the command line to see if you're getting errors from that. As it is you're not checking the status of ``subp.call`` which you should as it seems to be the whole purpose of the script.

Comment: Oh sorry J.F. That must have gotten messed up during my copying and pasting. I will try that sotapme, the files seem to be in the tmp directory when I run tmp ls though, after the error occurs.

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_call()` to assert that the ffmpeg command is successful. What does `sample_filename = sample_filename + '1' + image_ext` line do? You probably want to put it before `cmd =` line.